# div overlaying on text p tag

Tags: html, css

i created this jsFiddle and i wanted to know how could i adjust the `<p>` tag within the div so that the height is adjusted based on the text within and not for it to hide behind another div.

http://jsfiddle.net/qGzer/

```
<div class="nameImage"> 
    <div class="gridLetter">
            <div>A</div>
        </div>
        <figure class="thumbnail avatar circularGridVw">
            <img alt="Gravatar" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4425027572854858d9ebc2fe1c2fd847?s=150&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=G">

        </figure>
        <p>Jackie ThunderBirdies James</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to css of div

```
 position: absolute;



.gridLetter {
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: 4px;
display: block;
height: 17.7px;
     position: absolute;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qGzer/1/

Comment: If you try to add more text here it will overlay again with the next div

Answer (score 1):

Hi Just set an `height:auto`. See your code here http://jsfiddle.net/qGzer/23/

```
.nameImage {
  width:158px;
  height:auto;
}
```

Also i set the `float:left` to `display:inline-block` to reserve spaces in case of different heights of the divs.

Answer (score 0):

In your div you are limiting the height